# asp.net Repeater and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater with a checkbox in the item template.
During itemdatabound event of the repeater I add an attribute to the checkbox

```
 ((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkPresents")).Attributes.Add("accountName", ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["accountName"].ToString());
```

I have a button that suppose to get all the checked checkbox and the account name associated with it.

How can I do this using jquery.

Thanks very much.

Comment: what exactly is the error here? Can you post the JQuery ode you wrote that is not doing what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following things.

```
$(docuement).ready(function()
{
   $("#yourButtonID").live("click",function()
   {  
      $('input[id*="chkPresents"]:checked').each(function() // mathing all checked imputs

      {
         $(this).attr("accountName") ; //is your accountName
         $(this) //is reference to current  checkbox
       }
      )
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would alert the "accountName" attribute for all checked checkboxes -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#clickbutton").click(function () {
        $("input:checkbox[checked]").each(function () {
         alert($(this).attr("accountName"));
        }    
       )    
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/bV96D/